# Filtering kendo grid asp.net mvc by linq

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using kendo grid + asp.net

I have a lot of grids with filtering. I don't want to create filtering code for each grid and each column and duplicate code. 
I cannot find some solutions of these problem.
I see two ways: reflection and expressions trees.

Do you have some another way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the MVC wrappers and if your linq queries are returning `IQueryable<T>` then you can do something like this

```
public ActionResult MyData([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var query = dbContext.MyTable; // whatever your linq query may look like

    return Json(query.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

This will automatically take whatever filters/pagination/sorting your grid has and defer execution to the database.